# How to align text file with awk in python?

Tags: python, regex, awk, printf

I have this array:

```
dihedrals=['na-2e-na-cd   4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'Pd-2e-na-cd   4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'Pd-2e-na-ca  4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'Pd-4n-na-hn   4    4.800         0.000           2.000', 'na-4n-cc-cc   4    4.200       180.000           2.000', 'na-2e-na-ca   4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'Pd-2e-na-ca   4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'cc-4n-na-hn   4    4.800         0.000           2.000', 'Pd-4n-na-cd   4    4.800         0.000           2.000', 'Pd-2e-na-cc   4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'X -4n-na-X   2    3.400       180.000           2.000', 'Pd-4n-cc-h4   4    4.200       180.000           2.000', 'Pd-4n-cc-cc   4    4.200       180.000           2.000', 'na-2e-na-cd  4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'na-2e-na-cc  4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'cc-4n-na-cd   4    4.800         0.000           2.000', 'na-2e-na-ca  4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'Pd-2e-na-cc  4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'na-2e-na-cc   4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'Pd-2e-na-cd  4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'na-4n-cc-h4   4    4.200       180.000           2.000']
```

and I want to write it in a file like this:

```
na-2e-na-cd   4    1.200       180.000           2.000
Pd-2e-na-cd   4    1.200       180.000           2.000
Pd-4n-na-hn   4    4.800         0.000           2.000
na-4n-cc-cc   4    4.200       180.000           2.000
na-2e-na-ca   4    1.200       180.000           2.000
cc-4n-na-hn   4    4.800         0.000           2.000
Pd-4n-na-cd   4    4.800         0.000           2.000
Pd-2e-na-cc   4    1.200       180.000           2.000
X -4n-na-X    2    3.400       180.000           2.000
Pd-4n-cc-h4   4    4.200       180.000           2.000
Pd-4n-cc-cc   4    4.200       180.000           2.000
na-2e-na-cc   4    1.200       180.000           2.000
cc-4n-na-cd   4    4.800         0.000           2.000
na-4n-cc-h4   4    4.200       180.000           2.000
```

I tried:

```
!awk '{print $1"   "$2"    "$3"       "$4"           "$5}' a.txt
```

But awk sees extra field in this row: `"X -4n-na-X "` because there is a space next to `X` . I tried to change the field separator as two spaces with`-F="[[:space:]][[:space:]]+"`:

```
import os
    for x in range(len(dihedrals)):
        dihedrals[x]=os.popen('echo "{}" |awk -F="[[:space:]][[:space:]]+"  \'{{  printf "%0s %0s %0s %0s %0s",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}}\'  '.format(dihedrals[x])).read()
        print(dihedrals[x])
```

But nothing changed.
I also tried `printf %s`:

```
import os
for x in range(len(dihedrals)):
    dihedrals[x]=os.popen('echo "{}"|awk \'{{printf "%0s %3s %8s %13s %15s",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5}}\'  '.format(dihedrals[x])).read()
```

But again it didn't work. How can I write my variable into a file as I explained above?

I also tried python formatting, regex, exc... but I couldn't accomplish.

NOTE: I also tried `column -t a.txt` but again I am in trouble with X+space row (`X -4n-na-X`) Here is result:

```
na-2e-na-cd  4         1.200  180.000  2.000
Pd-2e-na-cd  4         1.200  180.000  2.000
Pd-2e-na-ca  4         1.200  180.000  2.000
Pd-4n-na-hn  4         4.800  0.000    2.000
na-4n-cc-cc  4         4.200  180.000  2.000
na-2e-na-ca  4         1.200  180.000  2.000
Pd-2e-na-ca  4         1.200  180.000  2.000
cc-4n-na-hn  4         4.800  0.000    2.000
Pd-4n-na-cd  4         4.800  0.000    2.000
Pd-2e-na-cc  4         1.200  180.000  2.000
X            -4n-na-X  2      3.400    180.000  2.000
Pd-4n-cc-h4  4         4.200  180.000  2.000
Pd-4n-cc-cc  4         4.200  180.000  2.000
na-2e-na-cd  4         1.200  180.000  2.000
na-2e-na-cc  4         1.200  180.000  2.000
cc-4n-na-cd  4         4.800  0.000    2.000
na-2e-na-ca  4         1.200  180.000  2.000
Pd-2e-na-cc  4         1.200  180.000  2.000
na-2e-na-cc  4         1.200  180.000  2.000
Pd-2e-na-cd  4         1.200  180.000  2.000
```

Comment: Why are you using `awk` for the formatting rather than just writing out the formatted output using Python?

Comment: I tried but 0.000 and 180.000 have different numbers of chars and it seemed distrupted.

Comment: could the 1st column have more than one occurrence of a space between characters? will the 1st column always have a max width of 11 characters?

Comment: @markp-fuso yes. for example it could be `c -c -c -c ` (4c with a space) or `ca-c -X -c ` exc...

Comment: I may have counted wrong. "expected output" is base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use formatted output in python for this array. We just need to split each line using 2+ spaces to get individual fields.

```py
import re

dihedrals=['na-2e-na-cd   4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'Pd-2e-na-cd   4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'Pd-2e-na-ca  4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'Pd-4n-na-hn   4    4.800         0.000           2.000', 'na-4n-cc-cc   4    4.200       180.000           2.000', 'na-2e-na-ca   4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'Pd-2e-na-ca   4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'cc-4n-na-hn   4    4.800         0.000           2.000', 'Pd-4n-na-cd   4    4.800         0.000           2.000', 'Pd-2e-na-cc   4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'X -4n-na-X   2    3.400       180.000           2.000', 'Pd-4n-cc-h4   4    4.200       180.000           2.000', 'Pd-4n-cc-cc   4    4.200       180.000           2.000', 'na-2e-na-cd  4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'na-2e-na-cc  4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'cc-4n-na-cd   4    4.800         0.000           2.000', 'na-2e-na-ca  4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'Pd-2e-na-cc  4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'na-2e-na-cc   4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'Pd-2e-na-cd  4    1.200       180.000           2.000', 'na-4n-cc-h4   4    4.200       180.000           2.000']
for i in dihedrals:
     a = re.split(' {2,}', i)
     print( "%-11s  %2s   %8s   %12s  %12s" % (a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]) )
```

**Output:**

```sh
na-2e-na-cd   4      1.200        180.000         2.000
Pd-2e-na-cd   4      1.200        180.000         2.000
Pd-2e-na-ca   4      1.200        180.000         2.000
Pd-4n-na-hn   4      4.800          0.000         2.000
na-4n-cc-cc   4      4.200        180.000         2.000
na-2e-na-ca   4      1.200        180.000         2.000
Pd-2e-na-ca   4      1.200        180.000         2.000
cc-4n-na-hn   4      4.800          0.000         2.000
Pd-4n-na-cd   4      4.800          0.000         2.000
Pd-2e-na-cc   4      1.200        180.000         2.000
X -4n-na-X    2      3.400        180.000         2.000
Pd-4n-cc-h4   4      4.200        180.000         2.000
Pd-4n-cc-cc   4      4.200        180.000         2.000
na-2e-na-cd   4      1.200        180.000         2.000
na-2e-na-cc   4      1.200        180.000         2.000
cc-4n-na-cd   4      4.800          0.000         2.000
na-2e-na-ca   4      1.200        180.000         2.000
Pd-2e-na-cc   4      1.200        180.000         2.000
na-2e-na-cc   4      1.200        180.000         2.000
Pd-2e-na-cd   4      1.200        180.000         2.000
na-4n-cc-h4   4      4.200        180.000         2.000
```

---

A gnu-awk solution would be:

```sh
... |
awk -F ' {2,}' -v RS=', *|\\]' '
gsub(/dihedrals=\[|\047/, "") {
   printf( "%-11s  %2s   %8s   %12s  %12s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't want tabs. This is a force field file and it must be exactly like this: between first and second column there must be 2 spaces. Other columns must be like as I explanied above and 180.000 and 0.000 mut be aligned  left to right (not right to left). Otherwise simulation program can't read my file.

Comment: it is in the question already. Please look "and I want to write it in a file like this:" line in the question.  I added the file as a code.

Comment: yes, absoluetly right.

Comment: input data is coming from a python program as an array. There is no file, just variable. ( it combines more than 50 file and generate "dihedrals" variable)

Comment: In that case won't it be better to do this in python itself?

Comment: I tried it but it was harder than it looks for this file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244447/discussion-between-baris-kurt-and-anubhava).

Comment: To get alignment right there would be 3 spaces between `X -4n-na-X` and `2`, is that how you want?

Comment: yes. that's true.

Comment: ok check output using python code. You can adjust width specifiers in `"%-11s  %2s   %8s   %12s  %12s"` to customize your output.

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- 1st column always consists of 11 characters

I don't use `python` so I'll simulate the behavior (`python` making repeated calls out to `awk`) with a `bash` array and a `bash/for` loop that calls `awk`:

Setup:

```
declare -a dihedrals=([0]="na-2e-na-cd   4    1.200       180.000           2.000" [1]="Pd-2e-na-cd   4    1.200       180.000           2.000" [2]="Pd-2e-na-ca  4    1.200       180.000           2.000" [3]="Pd-4n-na-hn   4    4.800         0.000           2.000" [4]="na-4n-cc-cc   4    4.200       180.000           2.000" [5]="na-2e-na-ca   4    1.200       180.000           2.000" [6]="Pd-2e-na-ca   4    1.200       180.000           2.000" [7]="cc-4n-na-hn   4    4.800         0.000           2.000" [8]="Pd-4n-na-cd   4    4.800         0.000           2.000" [9]="Pd-2e-na-cc   4    1.200       180.000           2.000" [10]="X -4n-na-X   2    3.400       180.000           2.000" [11]="Pd-4n-cc-h4   4    4.200       180.000           2.000" [12]="Pd-4n-cc-cc   4    4.200       180.000           2.000" [13]="na-2e-na-cd  4    1.200       180.000           2.000" [14]="na-2e-na-cc  4    1.200       180.000           2.000" [15]="cc-4n-na-cd   4    4.800         0.000           2.000" [16]="na-2e-na-ca  4    1.200       180.000           2.000" [17]="Pd-2e-na-cc  4    1.200       180.000           2.000" [18]="na-2e-na-cc   4    1.200       180.000           2.000" [19]="Pd-2e-na-cd  4    1.200       180.000           2.000" [20]="na-4n-cc-h4   4    4.200       180.000           2.000")
```

Proposed code:

```
for x in "${dihedrals[@]}"
do
    awk '{ f1=substr($0,1,11)
           split(substr($0,12),a)
           printf "%11s %2s %7s %12s %13s\n",f1,a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]}' <<< "${x}"
done
```

This generates:

```
na-2e-na-cd  4   1.200      180.000         2.000
Pd-2e-na-cd  4   1.200      180.000         2.000
Pd-2e-na-ca  4   1.200      180.000         2.000
Pd-4n-na-hn  4   4.800        0.000         2.000
na-4n-cc-cc  4   4.200      180.000         2.000
na-2e-na-ca  4   1.200      180.000         2.000
Pd-2e-na-ca  4   1.200      180.000         2.000
cc-4n-na-hn  4   4.800        0.000         2.000
Pd-4n-na-cd  4   4.800        0.000         2.000
Pd-2e-na-cc  4   1.200      180.000         2.000
X -4n-na-X   2   3.400      180.000         2.000
Pd-4n-cc-h4  4   4.200      180.000         2.000
Pd-4n-cc-cc  4   4.200      180.000         2.000
na-2e-na-cd  4   1.200      180.000         2.000
na-2e-na-cc  4   1.200      180.000         2.000
cc-4n-na-cd  4   4.800        0.000         2.000
na-2e-na-ca  4   1.200      180.000         2.000
Pd-2e-na-cc  4   1.200      180.000         2.000
na-2e-na-cc  4   1.200      180.000         2.000
Pd-2e-na-cd  4   1.200      180.000         2.000
na-4n-cc-h4  4   4.200      180.000         2.000
```

From a performance perspective I'd think the same (`awk`) logic should be doable within `python` thus eliminating the need for the repeated calls out to `awk` ... ???

Answer (score -1):

Do you have to use awk? It seems like something along these lines would accomplish the same goal in plain Python:

```py
with open('a.txt', 'w') as fp:
  fp.write('\n'.join(dihedrals))
```

Comment: it is not about just writing into file. it must be formatted as I explanied. I can write it as a file but there are extra spaces.

Comment: Are there lots of lines where the first element in the row contains a space?

Comment: yes it is more than 20k rows